# sqlalchemy query for one-to-many combined with many-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create sqlalchemy query, to get data from many-to-many and one-to-many relationship tables, I have three models: Doctor Patient Data.
many Doctors - many Patients, one Patient - many Data.
Here the models:

```
class DocModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "doc"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    
    patient = db.relationship("PatModel", back_populates="doc", secondary="docs_pats")


class PatModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "pat"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    data = db.relationship("DataModel", back_populates="pat", lazy="dynamic", cascade="all, delete")

    doctor = db.relationship("DocModel", back_populates="pat", secondary="docs_pats")


class DataModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "data"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    path = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False, nullable=False)

    patient_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pat.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    patient = db.relationship("PatModel", back_populates='data')
```

and many-to-many assosiation table:

```
class DocPat(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "docs_pats"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    doc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("doc.id"))
    pat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pat.id"))

    patient_id = db.Column(
    db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pat.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    pat = db.relationship("PatModel", back_populates='data')
```

the result I want is, with the given doc.id, e.g. 1, get all data of patient, that associated with doctor. What should query be for this result?

I was able to get patients connected with doctor with query:

```
s = PatModel.query.filter(PatModel.doc.any(id=1)).all()
```

which gives me patients that was added to doctor.id=1, But stuck with getting data with associated patient that associated with doctor 1.

Comment: How does `subject` fit into this?  Is that data related to the other data somehow ?

Comment: Also what version of sqlalchemy are you using ?

Comment: @IanWilson, edited, accidently put other related models. should be `patient`

Comment: @IanWilson `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1`

Comment: Sorry, still a little confused about this model.  Is the data related only to the patient or to the patient AND a doctor ?  Your schema says one thing but your description seems ambiguous.  `"Doctor Patient Data"`.

Comment: @IanWilson, sorry for delyaed response, data related only to patient, patient can have many data. doctor related only with patient with many-to-many association.

Answer (score 0):

This is using SA 1.4 with Python3.  It isn't clear to me what SA version that flask SA version is using.

It will be hard to mix `secondary` and an association object, ie. `DocPat`.

Probably better off just querying doctor and eager loading the relationships manually like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, subqueryload

class DocModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "doc"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)

    doc_pats = db.relationship("DocPat", back_populates="doc")


class PatModel(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "pat"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    #This prevents eager loading with options(), lazy="dynamic",
    data = db.relationship("DataModel", back_populates="pat", cascade="all, delete")

    doc_pats = db.relationship("DocPat", back_populates="pat")


class DataModel(db.Model):
    """ Doctor agnostic patient data. """
    __tablename__ = "data"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    path = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=False, nullable=False)

    pat_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pat.id"), unique=False, nullable=False)
    pat = db.relationship("PatModel", back_populates='data')


class DocPat(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "docs_pats"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    doc_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("doc.id"))
    pat_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pat.id"))
    doc = db.relationship("DocModel", back_populates="doc_pats")
    pat = db.relationship("PatModel", back_populates="doc_pats")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:
    d1 = DocModel(username='brown')
    p1 = PatModel(name='marty')
    p2 = PatModel(name='lorraine')
    d2 = DocModel(username='clara')
    p3 = PatModel(name='george')
    session.add_all([DocPat(doc=d1, pat=p1), DocPat(doc=d1, pat=p2), DocPat(doc=d2, pat=p3)])
    session.commit()
    p1.data.append(DataModel(path='/data', filename='scan1_1.pdf'))
    p1.data.append(DataModel(path='/data', filename='scan1_2.pdf'))
    p3.data.append(DataModel(path='/data', filename='scan3_1.pdf'))
    session.commit()
    print (d1.id)


with Session(engine) as session:
    from sqlalchemy.sql import select
    from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload, subqueryload
    patients = session.query(PatModel).join(PatModel.doc_pats).where(DocPat.doc_id == 1).options(
        joinedload(PatModel.doc_pats).joinedload(DocPat.doc),
        subqueryload(PatModel.data)).order_by(PatModel.id).all()
    for patient in patients:
        print (patient.id, patient.name)
        print ("\t", "PATIENT DOCTORS")
        for docPat in patient.doc_pats:
            print ("\t", docPat.doc.username)
        print ("\t", "PATIENT DATA")
        for datum in patient.data:
            print ("\t", datum.filename)
```

#### TAILEND OF OUTPUT

```
2023-03-22 22:33:39,687 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-03-22 22:33:39,692 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT pat.id AS pat_id, pat.name AS pat_name, doc_1.id AS doc_1_id, doc_1.username AS doc_1_username, docs_pats_1.id AS docs_pats_1_id, docs_pats_1.doc_id AS docs_pats_1_doc_id, docs_pats_1.pat_id AS docs_pats_1_pat_id 
FROM pat JOIN docs_pats ON pat.id = docs_pats.pat_id LEFT OUTER JOIN docs_pats AS docs_pats_1 ON pat.id = docs_pats_1.pat_id LEFT OUTER JOIN doc AS doc_1 ON doc_1.id = docs_pats_1.doc_id 
WHERE docs_pats.doc_id = %(doc_id_1)s ORDER BY pat.id
2023-03-22 22:33:39,692 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00023s] {'doc_id_1': 1}
2023-03-22 22:33:39,699 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT data.id AS data_id, data.filename AS data_filename, data.path AS data_path, data.pat_id AS data_pat_id, anon_1.pat_id AS anon_1_pat_id 
FROM (SELECT pat.id AS pat_id 
FROM pat JOIN docs_pats ON pat.id = docs_pats.pat_id 
WHERE docs_pats.doc_id = %(doc_id_1)s) AS anon_1 JOIN data ON anon_1.pat_id = data.pat_id
2023-03-22 22:33:39,699 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00024s] {'doc_id_1': 1}
1 lorraine
     PATIENT DOCTORS
     brown
     PATIENT DATA
2 marty
     PATIENT DOCTORS
     brown
     PATIENT DATA
     scan1_1.pdf
     scan1_2.pdf
2023-03-22 22:33:39,701 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```